# Extract full weeks and remaining days from date range in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, date-difference, sql-date-functions

I have a date range say `1-Jul-2016`  to `10-Jul-2016`. I want to extract number of  weeks and remaining days exists in that range like

```
No. of Weeks = 1 

No. of Remaining Days = 3
```

I know how to find days OR week difference using

```
DATEDIFF(DAY,@ArrivalDate,@DepartureDate)
DATEDIFF(WEEK,@ArrivalDate,@DepartureDate)
```

But how to find and get whether a date contains only full Weeks or Weeks and Days.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some data?

Comment: Actually I pass start and end dates to Stored Procedure which will extracts No. of weeks and Days. The reason behind this is to calculate Daily and weekly charges for a stay period.

Answer (score 1):

Try following query

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2016.07.01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2016.07.10'

SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 7 AS 'No. of Weeks', -- 1
    (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) % 7) + 1 AS 'No. of Remaining Days' -- 3
```

Comment: Thanks . will try it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2016.07.01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2016.07.10'

SELECT 
    -- DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 7 AS 'No. of Weeks', -- 1
    DATEDIFF(WEEK, @StartDate, @EndDate) AS 'No. of Weeks',
   (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) % 7) + 1 AS 'No. of Remaining Days' -- 3
```